# Implementing "Rate application" functionality on a Windows Store app

Tags: windows-8, winjs, rate

I am trying to implement rating functionality in a Windows Store application using HTML / Javascript.

I am showing a popup dialog similar to the one below within the application and when "Rate" is clicked I would like to redirect to the Marketplace where the user can then rate the application.

[image]

This is a task that can easily be done on Windows Phone 7 via the MarketplaceReviewTask.

Is there an API on Windows 8 that I could call to have this achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rate and Review link in the Settings charm will automatically appear for users other than yourself (since you can't rate your own app).

If you want a custom link somewhere, you can use LaunchUriAsync like Jim says, using this URI:

```
"ms-windows-store:REVIEW?PFN=[my-pfm]"
```

where my-pfm is "Package Family Name" which you will find in your application manifest.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a blog post I found that's helpful:

http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Default.aspx?tabid=67&EntryID=227

Comment: this link moved here: http://www.spritehand.com/2012/08/adding-rate-and-review-to-your-windows.html

Answer (score 2):

If you use [protocol activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx) ([LaunchUriAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh701480.aspx)) with the [URI format suggested here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/02/22/linking-to-your-apps-on-the-web.aspx) you'll get to your app's page on the Store; however, there's still an additional step for the user to click Write a Review.  There may be a way to deep link to it and I'll update if I find out.

Comment: O`Neil There is no need to ask the user about rate & review the app if the user already rated & reviewed. Then, How could i know that user has reviewed the app. or Not????